# Lottie animation is not repeating even after 'repeat' is set as true in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, lottie

I am using the [Lottie package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) available on pub.dev to display Lottie files. The animation is playing single time and is not repeating even after 'repeat' is set as true. Please suggest to me what I am missing. Thanks

```
 Lottie.asset(
              'assets/lottiefiles/40912-new-year-loop-background.json',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 450,
              repeat: true,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. Tried it myself and seems like there's a problem with this lottie animation itself (some paint boundaries issues). Hence, you may look for some other lottie animation instead.